# Regular expression to match characters inside a word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk, nltk-book

I am doing the `Pig Latin` text conversion:

One of the requirements is putting `qu` together.

What I did  `re.findall(r'^qu', token)`

but it only accepts `qu` together if the word/token starts with `qu`

If the word/token starts with `aqu` then it does not recognize `qu` together.

What I want is to recognize `qu` no matter the placement, including if it starts with `Qu`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove the caret. And instead of just `qu` maybe: `[Qq]u`. Is regex necessary though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `^` from it, that cause this. The caret mean basically "start the matching from the beginning of the line (token in your case)".

Comment: This should work. Just to contribute a little bit, when I have to work with regular expressions I always use https://regexr.com/ to check if I'm doing something right. You can find some similar sites on google.